# What's the technical reason why class constants can't be arrays in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, constants

Anybody knows the technical reason why this constraint is placed on PHP classes (at least in v5.1x)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constants cannot contain mutable types. A constant is a "variable" that cannot be changed; it cannot be assigned to, but if its value were mutable, then it *could* be changed just by mutating the value:

```
class SomeClass
{
    public const $array = array(0 => 'foo', 1 => 'bar');

    public static function someFunction()
    {
        self::$array[0] = 'baz'; // SomeClass::$array has now changed.
    }
}
```

Comment: "A constant is a "variable" that cannot be changed" WTF? "Deathstar is a red car that's blue." Fail!

Comment: @sims: Hence my use of quotation marks, to indicate that it's a tenuous comparison that shouldn't be taken literally and indeed is self-contradictory.

Comment: When writing about logic, it helps to be literal.

Comment: @sims: "variable" is the nomenclature that a novice would be happiest/most familiar with; I'm trying to put it in layman's terms. Also, I'm not writing about logic. It's quite clear what I mean, so stop being obtuse :)

Answer (score 5):

Arrays are variable - you can modify them. You can use a static property instead.

Answer (score 0):

Don't exactly know why, but you can initialize static array variable:

```
class myClass {
   public static $arr = Array ('foo', 'bar'); 
}
```

Note that arrays are variables, so you can modify them outside...